# Using Angular how can we make a call after completing bunch of asynchronous calls

Tags: angularjs, q

This is my code in controller

```
myFactory.getPoints().success(function (data) {
    $scope.points = data;
});

myFactory.getStates().success(function (data) {
    $scope.states = data;
});

myFactory.getLeases().success(function (data) {
    $scope.leases = data;
});
```

I am expecting $scope.leases gets the value after $scope.points and $scope.states gets their values. I learned that $q with .then is not synchronous. Is that right?

**Answer:** I have derived below from the answers

```
$q.all([
        myFactory.getPoints().success(function (data) {
            $scope.Points = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occurred while loading Points! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
        }),   //more, more, more

    ]).then(function () {
        myFactory.getLease().success(function (data) {
            $scope.leases = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occurred while loading Leases! " + data.ExceptionMessage;
        })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is **success() does return the original promise**. `then()` call returns a promise (resolved with a value returned from a callback) while `.success()` is more traditional way of registering callbacks and doesn't return a promise.

So a proper solution is

```
$q.all([
    myFactory.getPoints().then(function (response) {
      $scope.points = response.data;
      return response.data;
    }),

    myFactory.getStates().then(function (response) {
      $scope.states = response.data;
      return response.data;
    }),

    myFactory.getLeases().then(function (response) {
      $scope.leases = response.data;
      return response.data;
  })
]).then(function(responses) {
   // xxx
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can chain promises together in order to have them execute synchronously:

```
myFactory.getPoints().success(function (data) {
    $scope.points = data;

    return myFactory.getStates();
})
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.states = data;

    return myFactory.getLeases();
})
.success(function (data) {
    $scope.leases = data;
});
```

Comment: Not necessarily 3 promises. I have 5 promises which can be called asynchronously and the 6th call should be after the completion of all the other 5 calls.

Comment: @Venu check my answer you can get an idea how to chain a promise after five other functions.